# jquery Change date pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really stucked here. Basically I need to change a date pattern from;

YYYY-MM-DD

to

DD-MM-YYYY

Any jquery-guru out there who could help?

Comment: Where is it? In the HTML? In a form input? In a string variable?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

```
var date1 = "YYYY-MM-DD";
var n = date1.split("-");
date1 = n[2] + "-" + n[1] + "-" + n[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var split = $(date).split('-');
var newDate = split[2] + '-' + split[1] + '-' +split[0];
```

Where `date` could be: *2013-01-09*.

Comment: lol -   im usually too slow

Comment: @LeeMeador, 4 seconds, and it took me time to decide if it worth an answer...